# URL rewriting with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have WordPress running on Apache, I have some URL like this one:

> https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/?type=Manager

And I want it to be :

> https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/manager/

I tried different things such as:

```
RewriteRule ^?type=Manager$ manager/
```

but it's not working. With this one for example I'm getting a 500 error, and sometimes it just does nothing. I don't know if it's my htaccess config, or because it's WordPress or because I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Use this rule in your `.htaccess` instead:

```
RewriteRule ^fr/([^/]*)$ /fr/?type=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a Internal Server Error :/

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Looking at that, the rule could be conflicting with another. Have you tried placing the `RewriteRule` at the top?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, tried it and added https://pastebin.com/QvfVXLgi at the top of the file, change nothing on my url :/